# What is the best way to delete a record and then return to same view with slug and data?

Tags: laravel-5

I have an app that has articles to which comments can be attached.  I now want to give the user the function to delete a comment.  What I am struggling with is then returning the user to the same view after the delete.

I could do this in js but am trying to see if I can avoid it.

The article link is like this myapp/articles/1.  The slug (1) being the article id.  I pass along with this all comments with the same article id.

In my article view I have;

```
@if (count($comments) > 1)
    @foreach ($comments as $comment)
     <p><a href="deleteComment/{{ $comment['id'] }}"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> {{ $comment['details'] }}</p>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

In my controller I have;

```
public function deleteComment($id)
{
    $comment= Comment::where('id', $id)->first();
    $comment->delete();
    return view ('myapp/articles/'); //This is where I am puzzled.  How do I return user to myapp/articles/1?
}
```

Suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: In your deleteComment function, you could just search for the relevant article the comment belongs to before you delete the comment? I assume you have a one to many relationship between the articles and comments.

Comment: Yes, theatlasroom.  I can find the related article.  Question is, how to I redirect to my view myapp/article/(the article id)?

Comment: Get the article, store it in a variable ($article) then make the url to your view 'myapp/articles/'.$article->id and use a [redirect](https://laravel.com/docs/master/responses#redirects)

Comment: Yep, that's what I was looking for.  Thanks!